# Tomcat sever deployment connection closed

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I am deploying a grails(v 2.3.4) application in an Apache tomcat server (v 7.0.47) in a virtual machine.

```
WARNING: Failed to execute: select min(date_hour) as a, max(date_hour) as b from Tablev1 because: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

This happens after 12+ hours, I was checking online and it said this happens as the app is idle etc etc

Also, is it okay if I use some click automation process of closing and restarting server after every 12 hours? Is that a good solution for now?

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Also, if the users increase, will the tomcat server be able to hold it? Till how many users will this be there?

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is it okay if I use some click automation process of closing and restarting server after every 12 hours? Is that a good solution for now?

This is not really a solution at all, you're trying to hide the underlying problem rather than fix it.

As a first step to fixing the problem, check your production `dataSource` properties in `DataSource.groovy` against these recommended defaults:

```
properties {
    // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
    jmxEnabled = false
    initialSize = 5
    maxActive = 50
    minIdle = 5
    maxIdle = 25
    maxWait = 10000
    maxAge = 10 * 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    validationQueryTimeout = 3
    validationInterval = 15000
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = false
    jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
    defaultTransactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
}
```

Comment: Ok I have used this, lets see if it runs for 12+ hours now.
Will there ever be a time when the app will stop unless I close the server manually?

Also, I tested the web-app with 10 users using it for 5 minutes, it was running smoothly. Is there any limit to number of users here?

Comment: I am not able to deploy after using these properties it's giving several errors in the tomcat server !